# how to select all booleancheckbox using jsf primefaces?

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces

ok guys, i know theres another related question like mine, but i ve tried that solution but still not work at all. heres my jsf

```
<h:form id="store-news-check">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;padding:5px;margin-top:0px">
                        <ui:repeat value="#{dashboardBean.storeNewsList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
                            <li style="display:inline-flex;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 5px">
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.cmsCheck}" style="margin-bottom:0px" />
                                <a href="#" style="color:#333"><span class="task-name">#{item.storeId.name} - ${fn:substring(item.title,0, 10)} ....</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </ul>

                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{dashboardBean.selectAllNews()}" value="Select All" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-send" style="border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-send" style="border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px"/>
                </h:form>
```

and heres my backing bean

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        storeNewsList = storeNewsFacade.findStoreNewsDashbroad();

    }        

private List<StoreNews> storeNewsList;    

    public List<StoreNews> getStoreNewsList() {

            return storeNewsList;

        }

    public void selectAllNews(){
            for(StoreNews sn:storeNewsList){
                sn.setCmsCheck(true);
            }

            infoMessage("check all store news");
        }
```

hope you guys can help me, thanks !

Comment: So what **does** happen... how do the network responses look like, what does the list on the server look like when it is retrieved again... lots of things to investigate besides stating 'does not work'

Comment: sorry, first condition of list is all of list is uncheck, then i want when i click select all button, the list is turn to check. that it man.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you just need to update the checkboxes. For example with

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{dashboardBean.selectAllNews()}" update="@form" ... />
```

Also `type="button"` on the save-button seems not right.

Comment: Seems you're always calling findStoreNewsDashbroad() in the getter, so how can it show what you just selected when you call some service again? When you in xhtml say "#{dashboardBean.storeNewsList}" it means it calls the getter. Seems to me getStoreNewsList() must always return storeNewsList, and you must call findStoreNewsDashbroad() for example in a @PostConstruct-method

Comment: Seems better to me, so what happens now? I think the bean must be at least viewscoped

Comment: i set scoped as sessionScoped, now the storelistnews is not getting update, not like before. i tested it by check  some data and click select all, then the data that i check is not back to uncheck again. that good news. but still does not resolve my problem. select all still not working, i guess the problem is in selectallnews() method

Comment: i add some information for you, when i try to update some data column except cmsCheck column like title column with data type string, then the title are update ! but why cmsCheck with data type boolean still not update.

Comment: it work now, i have to put list inside dataTable not ui:repeat, thanks for help :)